# Suppose that $F'(x)\leq G'(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $F(x)\leq G(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-writing

Suppose that $F'(x) \leq G'(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $F(x) \leq G(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove or disprove. I came up with counterexample that  $\cos(x) \leq \cos(x)+1 $ for all $x$, but this does not imply that their antiderivatives $\sin(x) \leq \sin(x)+x $, if we choose any negative $x$ this will not hold. Am I right or wrong?

Comment: You need additional information about F and G. For instance, if you happen to know that $F(0) <= G(0)$ then you can get a proof off the ground.

Comment: You can find easier counterexamples, but the idea is right: you are free to add a constant to $F$ without altering $F'$, so if you take it sufficiently big, it will break the inequality $F(x)\le G(x)$.

Comment: @Dalton: But only for $x\ge 0$. At negative times inequality may well reverse. (More precisely, if $F(0)=G(0)$ and $F'(x)\le G'(x)$ then $F(x)\le G(x)$ for $x\ge 0$ and $F(x)\ge G(x)$ for $x\le 0$)

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Yes, of course. I should have been more precise. Thanks for mentioning that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler counter-example: $F(x) = 1$, $0 = G(x)$ :)

However it's true that: assuming $F(x_0) \le G(x_0)$ and $F'(x) \le G'(x)$ for $x \ge x_0$ we have $F(x) \le G(x)$ for all $x \ge x_0$.

Comment: Yeah, this counterexample is much simplier, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take any bounded function as $g(x)$ and take $f(x)$ as the function $g(x)$ shifted upward high enough that $g(x) < f(x)$ (we can do this if $g$ is bounded).  Then since shifting upward doesn't change the derivative (i.e., if $f(x) = g(x) + c$ then $f'(x) = g'(x)$), we have $f'(x) \leq g'(x)$ but $f(x) > g(x)$ for all $x$.

Here is an easy example of two lines which have the same slope (note that these aren't bounded as in my method above):

Let $f(x) = 3x + 1$ and $g(x) = 3x$.  (You should be thinking of these geometrically as the lines they are.)

Then $f'(x) = g'(x) = 3$, so $f'(x) \leq g'(x)$.

But it should be clear that $f(x) > g(x)$ for all $x$, so we don't have $f(x) \leq g(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Best you can say is $G'(x) \leq F'(x) \rightarrow (F(x)-G(x))' \geq 0 $ so that $F(x) \geq G(x) $.

Now this is true if we know if $F(x) > G(x)$ for just one $x>0$.

If $F(x)>G(x)$ for some x, then $F(x)-G(x)>0$ , then use that $(F(x)-G(x))'>0$, so that $F(x)-G(x) \geq 0$ is nondecreasing for $x>0$, so that $F(x)-G(x) \geq 0$.

Comment: Are you sure it's true?

Comment: I think so; the function $F(x)-G(x)$ is non-decreasing. But I think we need an additional condition that some value of F is larger than some value of G. Let me edit.

Comment: That won't be enough, just take $F(x) = 2x$ and $G(x) = x$. The inequality $F(x) \ge G(x)$ is true for $x = 0$, but not for $x = -1$.

Comment: Typo: That was $F(x)>G(x)$ And of course, inequalities reverse when we go into $( - \infty , 0)$

Answer (score 1):

The claim is wrong. Consider example like:

$F(x)=x, G(x)=2x-1$

So $F'(x)=1, G'(x)=2$, then

For all $x\in \mathbb{R}, F'(x)<G'(x)$, but

$\forall x<1,F(x)>G(x)$ and  $\forall x>1,F(x)<G(x)$